# knitr with ggplot and colorspace: object not found error

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I've checked with Google and especially here on stackoverflow, but did not find something like the problem that I ran into. I apologize in case I missed a report of this issue.

This is what happens: When I use a custom `knit()` function defined in the YAML header of my R markdown document, a variable that is used by the colorspace function `scale_fill_continuous_sequential()` throws an `object <...> not found` error. I tried a few different things, and think that I could narrow the problem down to some incompatibility between the custom `knit()` function and the use of a colorspace function with ggplot.

Here are three examples to demonstrate my observations:

1:

````
---
title: "lLim Error Example 1"
output: pdf_document
---

This does not use a custom knit() and works.

```{r main}

library("colorspace")
library("ggplot2")

myDF <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:10],
  y=c(2.7, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 1.9, 1.8, -2.1, -2.3, 2.1),
  c=c(2.4, 2.3, 2.1, 2, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4))

lLim <- 1.3
uLim <- 2.5

ggplot(myDF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=c)) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Y") +
  ggtitle(paste("lLim is", lLim)) +
  scale_fill_continuous_sequential(limits=c(lLim, uLim))
```
````

2:

````
---
title: "lLim Error Example 2"
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
    rmarkdown::render(inputFile, output_format='pdf_document',
      output_file=paste0(basename(inputFile),'.',Sys.Date(),'.pdf'))
    }
  )
---

This uses a custom knit() and does not work, throwing this error:
Error in ggplot2::continuous_scale(aesthetics, "continuous_sequential",  : 
  object 'lLim' not found

```{r main}

library("colorspace")
library("ggplot2")

myDF <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:10],
  y=c(2.7, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 1.9, 1.8, -2.1, -2.3, 2.1),
  c=c(2.4, 2.3, 2.1, 2, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4))

lLim <- 1.3
uLim <- 2.5

ggplot(myDF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=c)) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Y") +
  ggtitle(paste("lLim is", lLim)) +
  scale_fill_continuous_sequential(limits=c(lLim, uLim))
```
````

3:

````
---
title: "lLim Error Example 3"
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
    rmarkdown::render(inputFile, output_format='pdf_document',
      output_file=paste0(basename(inputFile),'.',Sys.Date(),'.pdf'))
    }
  )
---

This uses a custom knit() but not the colorspace function, and does work. Here knitr "sees" object 'lLim'.

```{r main}

library("colorspace")
library("ggplot2")

myDF <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:10],
  y=c(2.7, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 1.9, 1.8, -2.1, -2.3, 2.1),
  c=c(2.4, 2.3, 2.1, 2, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4))

lLim <- 1.3
uLim <- 2.5

ggplot(myDF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=c)) +
  xlab("X") + ylab("Y") +
  ggtitle(paste("lLim is", lLim)) +
  scale_fill_continuous()
```
````

I should add that all three examples work when being run interactively. The problem only comes when using `knit()`. In my case this is by using the Knit button in RStudio Pro version 1.2.1335-1 with R version 3.6.1, knitr version 1.23, ggplot2 version 3.2.1 and colorspace version 1.4-1.

The above examples should be reproducible as long as you save them in separate files.

There are probably work-arounds to this problem, but perhaps there is also a direct solution to the `object <...> not found` error.

Any insights will be appreciated!

Anton